# java code to generate javadocs html

Tags: javadoc

I am looking for a java code that generates javadocs HTML.

I made an API for my application, the APIs can be invoked via URLs

```
http://myurl/servletAPI?method=getData&param1=2010&param2=AC,BD,CLD
http://myurl/servletAPI?method=insertData&param1=AC,BD,CLD
```

I have few methods and each method with different number of parameters and moreover each method returns different format of data.  For instance method **getData** returns an xml formatted data and method **insertData** will return a string `success/fail`

I have included detailed javadoc comments in my servlet, now I wanted to show javadoc page to the user when he request URL `http://myurl/servletAPI` (without any parameters), it is basically a help page.

Can you suggest me a javacode that outputs the user a javadocs HTML in case of invalid URLs for my API.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to generate static HTML Javadoc pages (as part of your build, both Ant and Maven can do that easily, and you can also do it manually using your IDE or the command line), deploy those to your server and redirect to or include them from your help page.